# Can a Bluetooth end device limit what apps can connect to it?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, bluetooth

My company is looking at developing a mobile(Tablet) app that will need to connect to various sensors made by others using Bluetooth. These other companies have their own apps to connect with their individual sensors.

I need my app to be able to connect to their hardware (sensors).

Working with each manufacturer... What is the best way for their development teams to offer what I need without giving away all their code? In almost all cases their current sensor and app provide many more features than what we need.

Is there some middle ground where we ask only for the portions of code to perform the couple of functions we need?

Should they even be concerned about sharing their Bluetooth App code when they are the manufacturer of the sensor itself? Our app is only used to talk to their device which still needs to be purchased from them.

Comment: Most bluetooth accessory manufacturers, have their own API for connecting to their device. If the ones you are planning to use do not provide a usable API, I assume the bluetooth accessory manufacturers are open to making changes to their code to suite your need... if not an answer to this question wouldn't be much help...

Comment: Well the industry I work in is not known for being very techie, though we are quickly getting there. So currently the manufacturers feel their app should be the only way to talk to their device. I am trying to speak to the development teams, which in some cases are outsourced, to find out the possibilities of providing us with an API for our app. Is this the route I should be taking?

Answer (score 0):

It's going to depend on their business model. Just ask. If they are willing to open up their peripheral, they will provide you with the API. Some might charge you for the "SDK".

You may be able to become a vendor and sign some contracts to ensure that they will continue providing the peripherals and support for them to some degree.

If they say no, it's generally not a good idea to reverse engineer it outside of hobby work. If they change their API, you'll have to change the app, and maybe they'll change it just to make your app stop working.

They can't really limit what devices can connect to it, but knowing how to communicate with the peripheral and having any credentials that it might ask for, is a different matter.